# make li element a button phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, cordova

I want to have a button instead of a li in my phonegap app which I am doing.

Here's what It looks like

```
    <div class="menu-search">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span><input type="text" id="txtSearch" placeholder="Enter  Name"></span>
        </li>

        <li>
            <span><select name="selCategory" id="selCategory"></select></span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span><select name="selCity" id="selCity"></select></span>
        </li>
        <li>  <a class="" id="btnSearch">Apply Filters</a></li>
        <li> <a class="btn" id="btnClearSearch">Clear Filters</a></li>
        <li><a class="close-search" href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>Close<i class="fa fa-circle"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

I don't want to use bootstrap button here.

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrcyebrr/) for the same.

Please suggest.

Comment: Just use CSS and make a border, padding, maybe a color, … very easy.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you just want the CSS, if so, try this:

```
#buttons li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #000000;
    margin-right: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    line-height: 60px;
}    

#buttons li a{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        display: block;
    }

    #buttons li a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000000;
        background-color: #33B5E5;
    }
```

You can find more information here:  https://alextheedom.wordpress.com/code-and-stuff/creating-buttons-from-ul-element/